# Modelagem banco de dados Firebase: Relações n:n

Tags: banco-de-dados, firebase, nosql

Estou estudando firebase que utiliza NoSQL e me surgiu uma dúvida ao assistir esse video: [Convertendo estruturas SQL em estruturas Firebase - Firebase Database para desenvolvedores SQL #2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ran_Ylug7AE&index=2&list=PLl-K7zZEsYLlP-k-RKFa7RyNPa9_wCH2s)

Nele o autor cria uma estrutura como essa:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Blz...com essa estrutura ficaria muito fácil retornar todos os participantes de um determinado evento apenas percorrendo o nó eventAttendees.

Mas e se eu quiser saber todos eventos que um determinado usuario participa. Como eu faria? Se eu criar um outro nó usersAttendees eu conseguiria fazer isso salvando os usuarios e dentro de cada usuario os eventos que ele participa.

Mas ai temos um problema: duplicação de dados. Se houver uma modificação, digamos, se eu remover um evento do usuario David, eu vou ter que remover dos dois nós : eventAttendees e usersAttendees.

Isso seria facilmente feito usando SQL modelando como na foto mas o o objetivo aqui é fazer usando NoSQL:
[image: Estrutura em SQL]

Então minha dúvida é , qual é a melhor forma de modelar isso em NoSQL para evitar esse tipo de problema?

**EDIT**: percebi que esse problema persiste para qualquer relação n para n.
Então, especificando mais, minha dúvida seria como fazer relações n para n com NoSQL da melhor maneira possível?

Answer (score 0):

> Mas e se eu quiser saber todos eventos que um determinado usuario
>   participa. Como eu faria?

Você pode fazer uma consulta sem ter de alterar a sua estrutura. Por exemplo, para ver todos os eventos que o David participa:

```
var eventAttendeesRef = firebase.database() .ref().child("eventAttendees");
eventAttendeesRef.orderByChild('1').equalTo('David').once('value', function(dataSnapshot){
    dataSnapshot.forEach(function(snapshot){
        var eventoID = snapshot.getKey();
        console.log('O David participa do evento com ID: '+eventoID);
    });
});
```

> Como fazer relações n para n com NoSQL da melhor maneira possível?

O NoSQL não tem uma forma padrão de fazer relações n para n. Como você deve ter visto nessa série de vídeos do Youtube, você tem de estruturar os seus dados de acordo com a sua View. Procure sempre encontrar uma estrutura que reduz o número de queries necessárias para obter um dado. Nem que você tenha de [duplicar alguns dados](https://medium.com/android-dev-moz/firebasesql-39c882550f11) em algumas situações.